# SQL - How to get final quantity group by item unit?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have book stock table like :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   BOOK_ID     |   WAREHOUSE   |   UNITS   |   QTY_IN  |   QTY_OUT |
---------------------------------------------------------------------       
|       1       |       W01     |   PCS     |     5     |     0     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|       2       |       W02     |   BOX     |     1     |     0     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1       |       W01     |   PCS     |     20    |     0     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1       |       W01     |   BOX     |     2     |     0     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1       |       W01     |   PCS     |     0     |     2     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get final quantity for each book item, eg:

- for BOOK_ID 1 TOTAL QTY IS 2 BOX, 23 PCS
- for BOOK_ID 2 TOTAL QTY is 1 BOX
- so on..

This is I had tried so far :

```
select BOOK_ID, UNITS, WAREHOUSE, sum(QTY_IN) as QTY_IN, sum(QTY_OUT) as QTY_OUT from 
(select BOOK_ID, UNITS, WAREHOUSE, QTY_IN, QTY_OUT
from BOOK_STOCK) d
group by BOOK_ID, UNITS, WAREHOUSE
```

Please help me how to grouping and sum the quantity?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
select BOOK_ID,
       sum(case when units = 'BOX' then QTY_IN - QTY_OUT else 0 end) as QTY_BOX,
       sum(case when units = 'PCS' then QTY_IN - QTY_OUT else 0 end) as QTY_PCS
from BOOK_STOCK
group by BOOK_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do the trick for you.

```
select BOX.book_id, BOX.TotalQty as BoxFinalQuantity, PCS.TotalQty as PCSFinalQuantity
from 
(
select book_id, units, sum(qty_in-qty_out) as TotalQty from #Books
where units like 'BOX'
group by book_id, units) BOX
full outer join (
select book_id, units, sum(qty_in-qty_out) as TotalQty from #Books
where units like 'PCS'
group by book_id, units) PCS ON BOX.book_id = Pcs.book_id
```

Comment: Yours does the job but does more table scans making this query slower on large tables.

Comment: Why not a full outer join, in case a book_id has PCS but no BOX.

Comment: jarlh you're absolutely right. And your suggestion will probably work faster aswell.